# Как регулировать скорость 3х пиновых вентиляторов на корпусе?

Tags: железо

У меня материнская плата Asus ROG Strix Z270e, на корпусе есть вентиляторы (3pin) и они работают на полную катушку(без тот же эффект, если подключить вентилятор просто к блоку питания и не подключать к материнке). Возможно ли регулировать скорость вентиляторов? Подключаю в этот разъем(см. картинку)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: программно. найдите соответствующие программы под свою ОС

Comment: Программно не регулируется(А скорость процессорного кулера регулируется программно) , есть подозрение, что я не туда воткнул

Comment: в интеренете что то не очень вразумительно пишут. посмотрите какие опции для управления есть в биосе. особенно интересно нельзя ли переключать режимы управления с pwm на dc

Comment: У меня Asus prime z270-k и там есть переключалка pwm/dc в биосе

Answer (score 1):

Для управления 3-pin кулером нужно зайти в BIOS и в настройках QFan Control выбрать DC вместо PWM для CHA_FAN2.
Это есть в мануале *ASUS STRIX Z270E GAMING BIOS Manual* на стр 10, пункт 1.2.3 
QFan Control.

Answer (score 0):

А разве 3pin не означает, что 2 контакта под напряжение, 1 под съем данных по оборотам и 1 под управление оборотами, т.е. 3pin вообще такой возможности как управление оборотами не имеет, ни программные, ни аппаратные.

Поэтому управлять можно вручную через установку сопротивления.
Продаются переходники-реостаты, которые выполняют такую функцию.

(типа такого, в смысле прокладку между вентилятором и разъемом на материнской плате) 
http://www.price-altai.ru/uploads/900000/7500/907958/p17hjb3att1m5q3op1pvc1sgv1jos1.jpg

Посмотри это

https://pikabu.ru/story/tishina_v_pk_ili_reobas_svoimi_rukami_3296435